# WHERE IN sql query using Zend_Db

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Zend Framework beginner here. I'm trying to fetch all the Xbox titles of a video game database. One table contains games. Another table contains game types (ie. Xbox, Xbox Live Arcade, ...). I normally use the following query to get the Xbox titles.

**How can I execute the same query using Zend_Db?**

Thanks,

```
SELECT titleGame
FROM Game 
WHERE idGameType IN (
    SELECT idGameType 
    FROM GameType 
    WHERE nameGameType = 'Xbox')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That could be rewritten in Zend Framework a few ways.  Here is the way I typically write selects like that using [Zend_Db_Table_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html).

```
<?php

// For brevity, $dbTable = a Zend_Db_Table object

// first construct the subquery/join for the IN clause
// SELECT idGameType FROM GameType HERE nameGameType = 'Xbox'
$subselect = $dbTable->select()
                     ->from('GameType', array('idGameType'))
                     ->where('nameGameType = ?', 'Xbox'); // quotes Xbox appropriately, prevents SQL injection and errors

// construct the primary select
// SELECT titleGame FROM Game WHERE idGameType IN (subquery)
$select = $dbTable->select()
                  ->setIntegrityCheck(false) // allows us to select from another table
                  ->from($dbTable, array('titleGame'))
                  ->where('idGameType IN (?)', $subselect);

$results = $select->query()->fetchAll(); // will throw an exception if the query fails
if(0 === count($results)) {
    echo "No Results";
}else{
    foreach($results as $result){
        echo $result['titleGame'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

You can also write the SQL as a string, but when possible, the object-oriented approach is ideal because it makes the queries more portable, and most importantly makes it very easy to secure your queries.

Example:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();  // get the default Db connection
$db->select("select * from table where id = 3"); // doable, but not recommended
```

You can also create a [prepared statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html#zend.db.statement.creating) through `Zend_Db_Statement` to PHP's [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) extension.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE reported_by = ? AND bug_status = ?';
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($db, $sql);
$stmt->execute(array('goofy', 'FIXED'));
```

The first approach, the object oriented fluent interface is what you will see the most, and the method I would recommend starting out with and using.

Read through the [Zend_Db Manual Pages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html), and in particular, `Zend_Db_Table_Select`, `Zend_Db_Table`, and `Zend_Db_Adapter` for more information.  Even a quick read through over the [ZF Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) paying specific attention to the Db portion is helpful.  It will show how to set up table classes to be a gateway between your application and the database.

Comment: I gave it a try with no success (see the init function of my controller [here](http://pastebin.com/JnPdAnba)). I get an application error. The exception is "Select query cannot join with another table ". If I hard code the result returned by the embedded select it's fine though (see [here](http://pastebin.com/ejVSkxmw)).

Comment: since you are using the `Games` DbTable for the subquery which is querying `GameType`, try adding the `setIntegrityCheck(false)` after the `select()` portion of that query as well.  Or you could use a `Application_Model_DbTable_GameType` for the subselect and then you only need the `setIntegrityCheck(false)` on the second query the way it is now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT titleGame FROM Game
LEFT JOIN GameType ON GameType.idGameType = Game.idGameType
WHERE GameType.nameGameType = 'Xbox'
```

Why not use a join instead?  From my experience a subselect inside of `IN` is very slow in MySQL.

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->from('Game', array('titleGame'));
$select->joinLeft('GameType', 'GameType.idGameType = Game.idGameType', array());
$select->where("GameType.nameGameType = 'Xbox'");
```

Comment: I'll consider your answer. Desktop developer here. It's been awhile since I've worked with a database.