# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am preventing content to some unauthorized users, my condition works well, but while accessing this own controller i am getting error.
Please help me out.

```
$offer = new Application_Model_DbTable_Offers();
        $query = $offer->fetchAll($offer->select()
                                        ->from('vs_offers')
                                        ->where('id =?',$o_id)
                                        ->where('campaign_id IN (SELECT id from vs_campaign WHERE advertiser_id = ?)', $this->sessiondata->id));

if(count($query) < 1){
    $this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage('Unauthorize access');
    $this->_redirect('offers/');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of IN clause is bit different in Zend. One way is use [Zend_Db_Expr](http://zendframeworkdocumentation.com/classZend__Db__Expr.html) to perform IN clause operation like,

```
->where(new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('campaign_id IN
            (SELECT id from vs_campaign WHERE advertiser_id = %1$d)',
            $this->sessiondata->id)));
```

Another way is using [subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493552/696364).

Answer (score 0):

Highly likely that one of your parameters are null

`$o_id` or `$this->sessiondata->id`

**Reference to an old answer** - [ZF: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679770/zf-invalid-parameter-number-no-parameters-were-bound-error)